# Example for Introduction to Generics in Java

Tags: java, data-structure, data-types, generics

What are some good example classes for introducing generics in Java?

I'm introducing this in the context of implementing `ArrayList`, but I don't want my first example to be `ArrayList` itself due to the inability to create arrays of a generic type. I would also like my example to be something that doesn't seem contrived/has a practical use.

Comment: "Implementing" ArrayList or using the library class ArrayList from Collections?

Comment: You can pretty easily do a linked list.

Comment: @ncmathsadist Definitely, but I wanted to introduce generics between array list and linked list, so that we could start off using linked lists with generics. I'm happy with the pair example mentioned below - it went over well in class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While uniform collections are the obvious example, you can also build or use a Pair class in which the types of the two components are given by generic arguments. If you don't want to build it, there is a built-in class with this property: $Pair<K,V>$

But building one like it is simple enough if that is your goal.

Once you have your desired class, Write a function/method that needs to return two things instead of one. Bundle them up in a Pair.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! This is a very obvious one. I suppose that's what I get for making slides at night.